# How to know which row is switched on in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a UITableView myTable which has UISwitch for every row.

How can I find the row number of the table for which the switch is changed in my switchChanged method?

```
- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {
    UISwitch* mySwitch = sender;
    NSLog( @"%d", mySwitch.on );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion could be to use the tag.

When you setup the cell with the switch in `cellForRowAIndexPath:` you can set the switch tag to the row value. That way you can read out the tag again and get the row and item...

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one section (or just one section with switches using that method), you could store the row number in the switches' `tag` properties. Or if you limit yourself to reasonable numbers of sections and rows, you could store the section number in the high N bits and the row number in the low M bits of the tag integer (N+M < 32 for best results).

Or you could use `superview` from the switch until you find the UITableViewCell (test using `isKindOfClass:`), and then use `indexPathForCell:` on the table view to find the index path.

Or you could subclass UISwitch to have a property to store the index path.

Or you could use `objc_setAssociatedObject` to associate the index path with the switch.